# check to see if a button isClicked within a function jquery

Tags: jquery, function

I am trying to figure out a way to check if while a function is being checked to see if a button is pressed. If that button is pressed to display something. Its a bit complicated. So I have a previous and next button, but depending on what is currently being displayed, the prev and next functionality will change. Everything is being shown or hide so--I cant use back.history nor forward.history

Any way to check if a button is clicked from within another function?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#tear2").hide();
 $("#tear3").hide();
  $("#tear4").hide();

function pageCheck(){
if ($("#tear1").is(':visible')){
  
 if ($("#Prev").is(':clicked')){
    $("#tear1").show();
    }
    else if($("Next").is(':clicked')){
     $("#tear2").show();
      $("#tear1").hide();
    }
     
if ($("#tear2").is(':visible')){

  if($("#Prev").is(':clicked')){
      $("#tear2").show();
    
      alert("previous");
      
  }
      
  }
}
     

 }
   
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="tear1">This is me</div>
<div id="tear2">This is me</div>
<div id="tear3">This is me</div>
<div id="tear4">This is me</div>

<button id="Prev">prev</button>&nbsp;<button id="next">next</button>
```

Comment: This is what events are for. Set up an event for each button and put your logic in there.

Comment: A button can't get clicked while the function is executing. The button won't be "clicked" until the function finishes.

Answer (score 0):

You want the `$(".prev").on("click", function() {})` event handler and inside it something like (pseudocode-ish)

```
$(".mytears>.active").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
```

So putting it together

```
$(".prev").on("click", function() {
    $(".mytears>.active").removeClass("active").prev().addClass("active");
});
```

This isn't the entire logic (the `active` class needs a definition, you don't have a `mytears` container and it doesn't loop around to the beginning) but you get the idea of how it *should* be done.

Comment: why would .mytears need a container? what would it hold? wouldnt i need to listen for an event?

Comment: No, your #tears would need a container, or a common class. So you could select between them, get the previous next, first and last with just a single selector.